# How you can know if a Particular Screen has a "Menu" options available?

Tags: user-interface

I have 2 questions which are making my life difficult in using the Android phone a hell, may be I am/was an IPhone user.

1. I was wondering if there is anyway to know if current screen has "Menu" options available?
2. How I can know how many activities/screens are on the stack?

Comment: uhm same goes for the iPhone, how do you know you can 'tap'/'long tap' the screen to do something

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question? If not, try asking at the [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6):

1. Press the Menu button and see if anything happens.
2. Count.

If you're looking for a programmatic answer, you should be asking on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).